# Why Rails number_field form Builder accepts a floating value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails form builder with `number_field` as follows:

```
= f.number_field :integer_value, :step => 1, :class => 'form', :value => obj.value
```

it generates the html as:

```
<input class="form" id="people_attributes_232322900500_integer_value" name="people[people_attributes][232322900500][integer_value]" placeholder="" step="1" type="number">
```

But still it accepts a float value.

params that I gets in server side is as

```
{........, "integer_value"=>"12123.323"}
```

Comment: In which browser are you testing this?

Comment: depends on the browser

Comment: I am testing this in Safari

Comment: If you know the constraining range you could make this a select box instead and pass in a range e.g. `f.select :integer_value,(1..500).to_a`

Comment: @apneadiving thx, you are right.. I tested in chrome, it works..but it fails when I enter:  '2323.' , a number following a dot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a due to rails. input type='number' is a HTML5 construct and it provides only number to be provided in this field. It do not restrict user from entering non numeric characters.

Though most of the browser would apply client side validation on this field and when you try to submit a form validation errors would be show.
Note: validation error depends completely on browser and browser version

You should apply server side validation on field to be sure that non numeric field is not accepted
Check answer provided by zwippie for server side validation

ref link: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number

Answer (score 2):

You still have to validate the number in the backend, for example:

```
validates :integer_value,
  :presence => true,
  :numericality => { :only_integer => true, :greater_than => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to  => 100 }
```

For the input element, add `min="0"` to limit the values to integers. Still, it is possible for the user to enter a floating point number in all/most browsers.

Comment: Good answer. I would like to add: Step only specifies how much to increment/decrement the value when the user clicks the +/- buttons. It does not coerce the value into an integer.